# Make two jars from same project

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I have one monolith project in Java, and now it doesn't use maven. This project is CLIENT and SERVER project and is a GUI, so there are swing forms.

With the IDE I'm currently using (JDeveloper) I can make one jar for SERVER and one jar for CLIENT.

Now I want to migrate an actual project on maven to use NetBeans IDE I must obtain two jars from the same project, SERVER and CLIENT.

Is there a way to obtain this with some maven plugin?

If there isn't, is there a way to "duplicate" a project in a submodule project to have two jars from one source?

Comment: You could use the same jar for both, but provide a command line paremeter to run as client or server.

Comment: Best would be to separate the components for server and client which can create the approriate jar's and define commons parts into an other module... means to create a multi module build of it. It's the cleanest way to do that... Profiles are not a good way and make it more complicated than needed.

Comment: I think that the comment of khmarbaise is a better way

Answer (score 1):

You can make a multi-module maven project.

Configure your monolith code base in the root of the project. Check it compiles via `mvn clean install`.

Now add 2 submodules, `client` and `server`. Have both modules add a dependency to the root maven module.

Then filter out the classes you want to include in client.jar and server.jar via package name filtering using a `<build>` filter.